# How to setup bitcoin network using regtest?

Tags: regtest

My question might seem really basic , but I am looking for help as to how can I setup bitcoin network using regtest?

Comment: you can try the instructions at https://blog.starapps.io/setup-private-bitcoin-regtest-using-docker-a406127192df

Comment: I created a simple docker setup which allows you to run a private 3 node network here https://github.com/FreekPaans/bitcoin-multi-node-regtest

Answer (score 2):

2 ways.

1. `bitcoind --regtest --printtoconsole`
2. Configure bitcoin.conf and include a line `regtest=1`.

Second way is better so usage of bitcoin-cli is less verbose.

Comment: nice- looks good!