# trouble with bitcoin cli regtest

Tags: testnet, regtest

These are the commands I'm running after building a [clean ubuntu docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/smatthewenglish/oakcoin/) with all the dependencies:

```
./src/bitcoin-cli -regtest &
```

It yields the error:

```
error: too few parameters (need at least command)
```

Next I ran:

```
./src/bitcoin-cli -regtest -daemon
```

which resulted in:

```
error: too few parameters (need at least command)
```

finally:

```
./src/bitcoin-cli -regtest 101 &
```

yields:

```
error: Could not locate RPC credentials. No authentication cookie could be found, and no rpcpassword is set in the configuration file (/root/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf)
```

These commands have been taken from the following resource:

https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-examples#regtest-mode

There's a [question here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/28107/bitcoin-is-not-connected-in-regtest-mode), and a corresponding answer that provides a script to start regtest, is that a good solution?

To stop the daemon use the interface or run `bitcoin-cli stop`.

---

**Next step**

so I ran first:

```
bitcoind -regtest -daemon
```

and I got the output:

```
Bitcoin server starting
```

then I tried:

```
bitcoin-cli -regtest getinfo
```

which resulted in:

```
error: Could not locate RPC credentials. No authentication cookie could be found, and no rpcpassword is set in the configuration file (/root/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf)
```

these commands also generated the same output as above:

```
./src/bitcoin-cli -regtest help  
./src/bitcoin-cli -regtest 101
```

so I've created the following file:

```
vim /root/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf
```

it's literally just this:

```
rpcpassword=123
```

*also tried with this:

```
server=1
rpcuser=root
rpcpassword=password
rpcconnect=127.0.0.1
rpcport=8332
```

and now issued the command:

```
bitcoin-cli -regtest getinfo
```

which resulted in the following:

```
error: couldn't connect to server: unknown (code -1)
(make sure server is running and you are connecting to the correct RPC port)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems you're mixing up `bitcoind` and `bitcoin-cli`.

`bitcoind` is the Bitcoin Core daemon. It must be running first before you can do anything. `bitcoin-cli` is a tool to send RPC commands to a running `bitcoind` instance.

From the linked documentation page:

> bitcoind -regtest -daemon

No need to put a `&` after the command if you run with `-daemon`.

Once `bitcoind` is running, you can for example send the `getinfo` command using `bitcoin-cli`:

> bitcoin-cli -regtest getinfo

Or send `generate 101` to generate 101 blocks:

> bitcoin-cli -regtest generate 101

To learn about other commands you can send:

> bitcoin-cli -regtest help

That way you could for example learn about the `ping` command. To learn more about that, you can send:

> bitcoin-cli -regtest help ping

You need to specify `-regtest` for every command, as you can have a daemon running for each network (one for mainnet, one for testnet, one for regtest), or more if you configure each to run in separate directories and network ports.

Note that `bitcoin-cli` is just a program that speaks JSON-RPC (which is a standardized protocol), albeit somewhat specialized for use with `bitcoind`. You can connect to `bitcoind` using any JSON-RPC client (for which libraries exist in all popular languages). To do so, you'll need to [configure a username/password for connecting](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-examples) to `bitcoind`.

To explain what you are seeing:

- `./src/bitcoin-cli -regtest &` won't work as `bitcoind` is not yet running, and you aren't specifying a command to send.
- `./src/bitcoin-cli -regtest -daemon` likewise.
- `./src/bitcoin-cli -regtest 101 &` looks almost right, except you missed the `generate`, so you're trying to send the non-existing command `101` to a daemon that is not yet running.

Comment: you're exactly right that I was confused about `id` and `cli`, In **Next step** in the OP I tried to follow your guidance but also I seem to have messed it up, or it otherwise didn't work, I tried to write exactly what I've done, do you see what I've done wrong?

Comment: You can't change bitcoin.conf while bitcoind is running. Either no rpcuser/rpcpassport is set when bitcoind starts, and it'll use cookie authentication, or it is set, and both bitcoind and bitcoin-rpc will use it.

Comment: aha- ok. also I started the network like this: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/45881/how-to-setup-bitcoin-network-using-regtest which seemed to be better- but now it crashes because the size of my docker container is too small :/ need to figure out how to resize it